# Creating a redirect in IIS6

Tags: redirect, iis-6

I need to create a redirect from www.domain.com/page to another page in a different domain. I need the first (referring) url to have no extension (meaning no .html or .asp).

I know how to do it in Apache, but have no clue how to work with iis6.

Is there any simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy solution:

Create a folder for your website www.domain.com and then another sub folder for "page".

Create a website in IIS manager for www.domain.com
Expand that website, and then right click on your "page" folder, choose properties.

On the directory tab, choose the option: A redirection to a URL put the full domain of the target location.  You may also want to examine the check boxes below it if that fits your needs.

Another option that you could do outside of IIS is setup your website, and take advantage of the "default document".  if you add an index.html file into your website at http://www.domain.com/page , the default document will be called automatically without referencing the index.html in your path and you can do a javascript redirect.

```
<script>
window.location='http://www.someothersite.com/page.html'
</script>
```

This may be easier when dealing with a large number of pages.